# How to typeset a cover page with an image

Tags: graphics, book-design, covers, bookcover

Say I have a book title I want to typeset using latex:

```
 __________________
|                  |
|   ____________   |
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|  |   IMAGE    |  |
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|   ____________   |
|                  |
|                  |
|            Title |
|__________________|
```

The image is a transparent PNG of an organic subject so you won't actually see a rectangle. The image is just scaled down (from lets say 1500x3000px to however it should be scaled to fit on an 8x10 book cover. The the title goes below the image on the right. I have basically this MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,4mm,5mm]{book}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black
}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeXReset]{MyMonospaceFont}
\newlength{\characterwidth}
\setmonofont{black}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase
]
\settowidth{\characterwidth}{\normalfont x}
\geometry{
  left=24mm,
  right=24mm,
  top=24mm,
  bottom=40mm,
  footskip=24mm
}
\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright}
\frenchspacing

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\Huge\bfseries\null\vfill\fontsize{8mm}{12mm}\selectfont}
{\thechapter}
{0pc}
{}
[\newpage]

\definecolor{G1}{HTML}{777777}

\newcommand{\ga}[1]{\textcolor{G1}{#1}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\chapterfont{\fontsize{8mm}{12mm}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{4mm}{6mm}\selectfont}
\paragraphfont{\fontsize{4mm}{6mm}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\c}[1]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\l}[1]{\input{#1}}
\newcommand{\s}[1]{\section*{#1}}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\paragraph*{#1}}
\renewcommand{\t}[2]{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \null\vfill
    \begin{flushright}
    \fontsize{16mm}{24mm}\selectfont #1

    \fontsize{8mm}{12mm}\selectfont #2
    \end{flushright}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \end{titlepage}
}
\renewcommand{\o}{\tableofcontents}
\renewcommand{\i}[1]{\includegraphics{#1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fontsize{4mm}{6mm}\selectfont \thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{}
}
\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \chead{}
  \lfoot{}
  \cfoot{}
  \rfoot{}
}

\begin{document}

% first page is cover of book.

\begin{center}
  \i{img.png}
\end{center}

\begin{titlepage}
  \null\vfill
  \begin{flushright}
  \fontsize{100mm}{120mm}\selectfont #1
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

% chapters of book

% back cover of book
```

How to accomplish this? Ideally it would be possible to do this on a cover *and* a "back cover" page too :)

Comment: The biggest aspect is how to position the image and the title in the right place.

Comment: @LancePollard Please use `\begin{picture}...\end{picture}` tags for position the image...

Comment: @MadyYuvi please show how, just adding that gives me all kinds of errors.

Comment: @LancePollard I meant that you can use the `picture` environment to position the image in an easy manner, e.g., `\begin{picture)(0,0)\put(0,0){\includegraphics{...eps}}\end{picture}`, I didn't mean other than this...

Comment: Doing your last comment I end up with this, where it should show a complete figure it only shows a portion, and the title is pushed to page 3 :/ https://imgur.com/EuZsOXS

Comment: @LancePollard Use [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) instead. The cover of the book should be typeset in a separate document, because it should be typeset with different margins than the rest of the book. If you use [scrbook](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook) instead of standard `book`-class, you have all the necessary sections already defined.

Comment: I want it to be in one document like you see on Amazon books or scanned Google books.

Comment: It is no problem to combine several PDF-files using [pdfpages](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). However, [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) is able to place `textblocks` in the margins, so you be well served by my answer, in particular if you change to `scrbook`.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please change the code to n MWE that compile on standard systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) is a possibility. You place the image in one `textblock`-environment and title in another and change the the coordinates to suite you.

It is not necessary to define a macro for each element, but it is then easy to change layout if you have many items.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\image}{%
  \begin{textblock}{200}(20,20)
      \includegraphics*[height=200mm, width=160mm]{C:/temp/lisa-simpson.png}%
  \end{textblock}%
  }

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mytitle}{%
  \begin{textblock}{150}(130,230)
      \Huge\bfseries This is my title%
  \end{textblock}%
  }

\begin{document}

\image
\mytitle

\end{document}
```